# Can't get result in php from second select in the MS-SQL stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, ezsql

I have stored procedure:

```
USE [Auth]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[User_InfoByLogin]
@login nvarchar(10)
AS
begin

declare @id_client numeric(18,0)
declare @id_session numeric(18,0)

select @id_client=id from auth_Clients where [login]=@login

if @id_client is null
begin
    select -1 err, 'Пользователь не найден' err_msg,'' err_sys_msg
    return
end


select 0 err, 'Успешное получение данных' err_msg,'' err_sys_msg

select
cl.[login] as login,
cl.email,
cl.active,
convert(varchar, cl.date_reg, 104) as date_reg,
cl.space,
cl.id_ext,
cl.blocked,
cl.stopped,
convert(varchar, cl.stopped_date, 104) as stopped_date,
fz.name_First,
fz.name_Last,
fz.name_Father,
tf.limit_device,
tf.limit_cam,
tf.limit_video,
ct.id_tax as tarif
from 
auth_Clients cl
join auth_ClientsFz fz on cl.id=fz.id_client
LEFT JOIN auth_ClientTaxes AS ct ON cl.id=ct.id_client
LEFT JOIN auth_Tarifs AS tf ON ct.id_tax=tf.id
where 
fz.id_client=@id_client

end
```

and some php code executing this stored procedure:

```
public static function GetUserInfo($procName, $params){
    $conf = new Config();
    $conf->Init();
    if ($conf){ 
        $callProc = "exec $procName 
        @login = '$params[login]'
        ";              
        $user_info = $conf->db->get_results($callProc);
        echo 'OK';
        $conf->db->vardump($user_info);
    }
    else{
        echo 'Ошибка подключения к базе данных';
    }
}
```

All i'm getting is the result of first select:

> OK ezSQL (v2.17) Variable Dump..
>
> Array (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [err] => 0
>               [err_msg] => Успешное получение данных
>               [err_sys_msg] => 
>           )
>
> )
>
> Type: Array Last Query [1]: exec User_InfoByLogin 
>             @login = '9193390677' Last Function Call: $db->query("exec User_InfoByLogin 
>             @login = '9193390677'") Last Rows Returned: 1

I'm using ezsql connecting to and working with db:

```
//данные для подключения к бд
    public $db_name = '******';
    public $db_host = '******';
    public $db_user = '******';
    public $db_pass = '******';
    //база данных для ez sql
    public $db;

    public function Init(){
        $this->db = new ezSQL_mssql($this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name, $this->db_host);
    }
```

Is there any option to get the result from second select, exept merging them into one select statement?

Comment: Can you post the English conversion of the error message text.

Comment: [err_msg] => Успешное получение данных - "Successful data acquisition"

Comment: Your stored procedure is returning the 1 row. did you look what it is returning ?

Comment: http://f6.s.qip.ru/iaKRE5d8.png It's a result of this select from stored procedure: "select 0 err, 'Успешное получение данных' err_msg,'' err_sys_msg"

Comment: So you want both the message from first select and the second selects value ?

Comment: yep, that's exactly what i want. And other coder asked me not to change the code of stored procedure

Comment: There's no good simple way to do this, without a hack or a major paradigm shift. It looks like the best way is to just combine them together. Using the variable or union or get them in single query.